# Compute SIFT descriptor from given 2D points

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I would like to compute SIFT descriptors from given 2D points with OpenCV.
Given 2D points means:
I only have the coordinates of SIFT keypoints and I don't have the size and angle information of them.

The simple idea is using SIFT keypoints detector again and computing their descriptor. Then, we can pick up points that have the same coordinates of key points and given points.
But we have to use SIFT keypoints detector twice in this idea.

Do you have any idea of computing SIFT descriptor from given 2D points?
Thank you!

Comment: If you have coordinates of SIFT at first how do u get them. In ur situation if you will compare the same coordinates, in 2nd applying maybe u can miss some points also.

Comment: I get 2D points of SIFT feature from COLMAP.
https://colmap.github.io/database.html